# RealmPlugin (Swift) v0.92.2 leads to Shell Script Invocation Error

Tags: ios, xcode, realm

in order to create the latest realm-models, I am trying to install the Xcode RealmPlugin as described [here](http://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/).

Using Xcode 6.3 under iOS v10.10.3, I am trying to run "plugin/RealmPlugin.xcodeproj" (as described in the above link) - and I end up with the following error messages (see below).

I already tried to give access rights to the corresponding folders - but without success ! Any idea what to do ?

```
cp: file_templates/Realm Model Object.xctemplate: unable to copy extended attributes to /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Realm/Realm Model Object.xctemplate: Permission denied
cp: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Realm/Realm Model Object.xctemplate/___FILEBASENAME___.h: Permission denied
cp: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Realm/Realm Model Object.xctemplate/___FILEBASENAME___.m: Permission denied
cp: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Realm/Realm Model Object.xctemplate/TemplateIcon.icns: Permission denied
cp: /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/Realm/Realm Model Object.xctemplate/TemplateInfo.plist: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by giving permission rights (read&write) to every subfolder and files from below /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/...